# SPWeb.User is not returning newly created user

Tags: sharepoint

I am using sharepoint 3.0 and I do the following:
1. Create a user in the server
2. Go to sharepoint site and associate a group with this newly created user (I could not use common name of user to search for the user, I had to use the login name :S)
3. Create an item in one of the list and use this user
4. Login to the site with this user
5. Reset IIS

**Problem**: In a console application that is running in server, I call SPWeb.AllUsers and it is only returning old users that were there from past(for example administrator) and not returning this newly created user. What part of the puzzle am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [SPWeb.SiteUsers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spweb.siteusers.aspx) that returns users that are added to site collection.

SPWeb.Users return you users that are only explicitly added to that web (unique permissions), however SPWeb.AllUsers give you SPWeb.Users + those that have visited that web.

Answer (score 1):

You could also try the SPWeb.EnsureUser() method to check whether the user actually exists. Furthermore, users are stored in a hidden list in Sharepoint that's accessible only to site admins. More info on that [here](http://www.zimmergren.net/archive/2008/06/25/sharepoints-hidden-user-list-user-information-list.aspx).

Comment: The users list is simply hidden, but everyone has read access to it. It is possible to query that list using web services or SharePoint API from a regular user's account. The only problem is that you have to know the GUID of that list (and regular users cannot see the list in SPWeb.Lists collection)